# AngularJS: Retain dropdown option after form submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS to populate a dropdown, is there a way to retain which option was chosen after a form submit?

I'm also using PHP so I have the $_POST values, which I would usually write something like:

```
<?php if ($_POST['dropdown'] === 'this value') { ?> selected<?php } ?>
```

But I cannot in this case as the options are in a loop:

```
<option ng-repeat="type in Types" value="{{type.Name}}">{{type.Name}}</option>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to make an ajax call to get the submitted value and then set the selected property in the dropdown using ng-selected: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected

Angular generally is for single page applications with no postbacks, hence the hackery needed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. I've been using it mostly for it's data binding. I should probably switch to a lighter framework :) I also thought of hardcoding the dropdown options so I can add the selected PHP into them.